# Cargar CSS en flask Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-3.7

tengo un problema con mi aplicación flask, el problema reside cuando yo redirecciono a otra plantilla html con redirect y url_for, la cual no me carga los css.

Tengo esta estructura en el proyecto:

```
App
 |---auth
 |    |---__init__.py
 |    |---route.py
 |---user
 |    |---__init__.py
 |    |---route.py
 |
 |---manage.py(archivo que corre al inciar la aplicacion)
```

Yo hago la autenticación en la carpeta ***auth*** en el archivo **route.py**, y al redireccionar al archivo **route.py** que se encuentra en la carpeta ***user***, pero no me cargan los css predeterminados.

el código de ***auth/route.py***

```
        if DB.Users.select().where( DB.Users.username == username ).exists():
            USER = DB.Users.get( DB.Users.username == username )
            pass_enc_dec = USER.password.encode()
            if bcrypt.checkpw(password_encode, pass_enc_dec):
                return redirect(url_for('User.User', username=USER.username))
```

el código de ***user/route.py***

```
@app.route('/user/<string:username>')
def User(username):
    return render_template('user.html', username=username)
```

Comment: Aún no tengo la reputación suficiente para comentar. Donde se encuentra tu css y html?
Puede ser que no lo hayas enlazado correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final pude solucionar el problema, mi error fue no usar el utr_for cuando solicito mi CSS.

Lo Tenia de esta forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
```

Y lo corregí de esta forma

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css' ) }}">
```